# Program Crashes when on ViewHolder in listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I Have pasted my code below, the concept is I am having 3 different types of listview items that could be seen by viewholder classes. Now When i scroll the listview it crashes on `freeTextHolder = (ViewHolderFreeText) rowView.getTag();` as the `_position` is not matching the desired object of `itemList` the position shows that its a `"free text"` so `if (itemList.get(_position).getType().compareTo(Question.TYPE_CATEGORY) == 0)` gets true but `rowView.getTag()` shows its a checkbox so the `_position` 1 incremented then the desired position and it crashes.

```
    @Override
public View getView(final int _position, View _convertView,
        ViewGroup _parent) {

    View rowView = _convertView;
    if (itemList.get(_position).getType().compareTo(Question.TYPE_CATEGORY) == 0) {
        ViewHolderBranch branchHolder = new ViewHolderBranch();

        // Compartment for Branch
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_branch, _parent,
                    false);

            branchHolder.hTextTitle = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textTitleB);
            branchHolder.hTextDetail = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textDetailB);
            branchHolder.hIcon = (ImageView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageArrow);

            rowView.setTag(branchHolder);
        } else {

            branchHolder = (ViewHolderBranch) rowView.getTag();
        }

        branchHolder.hTextTitle.setText(itemList.get(_position).getText());
        if (itemList.get(_position).isIsReadCode())
            branchHolder.hTextDetail.setText(itemList.get(_position)
                    .getReadCode());
        else
            branchHolder.hTextDetail.setText(" ");
        branchHolder.hIcon
                .setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);

        // return rowView;
    }

    else if (itemList.get(_position).getType()
            .compareTo(Question.TYPE_CHECKBOX) == 0) {
        // Compartment for Checkboxes

        ViewHolderCheckbox checkboxHolder = new ViewHolderCheckbox();

        // Compartment for Branch
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_checkbox, _parent,
                    false);

            checkboxHolder.hTextTitle = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textTitleCB);
            checkboxHolder.hTextDetail = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textDetailCB);
            checkboxHolder.hCheckBox = (CheckBox) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            rowView.setTag(checkboxHolder);
        } else {

            checkboxHolder = (ViewHolderCheckbox) rowView.getTag();
        }

        checkboxHolder.hTextTitle
                .setText(itemList.get(_position).getText());
        if (itemList.get(_position).isIsReadCode())
            checkboxHolder.hTextDetail.setText(itemList.get(_position)
                    .getReadCode());
        else
            checkboxHolder.hTextDetail.setText(" ");
        checkboxHolder.hCheckBox.setChecked(itemList.get(_position)
                .isChecked());

        // return rowView;

    }

    if (itemList.get(_position).getType().compareTo(Question.TYPE_FREETEXT) == 0) {
        ViewHolderFreeText freeTextHolder = new ViewHolderFreeText();

        // Compartment for Branch
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_button, _parent,
                    false);

            freeTextHolder.hTextTitle = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textTitleBtn);
            freeTextHolder.hTextDetail = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textDetailBtn);
            freeTextHolder.hIcon = (ImageView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imagePlusBtn);

            rowView.setTag(freeTextHolder);
        } else {

            freeTextHolder = (ViewHolderFreeText) rowView.getTag();
        }

        freeTextHolder.hTextTitle.setText(itemList.get(_position).getText());
        if (itemList.get(_position).isIsReadCode())
            freeTextHolder.hTextDetail.setText(itemList.get(_position)
                    .getReadCode());
        else
            freeTextHolder.hTextDetail.setText(" ");
        freeTextHolder.hIcon
                .setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add);

        // return rowView;
    }

    return rowView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return itemList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int _position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return _position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int _position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return _position;
}
```

and the view Holder Classes are

static class ViewHolderBranch {
        TextView hTextTitle;
        TextView hTextDetail;
        ImageView hIcon;
    }

```
static class ViewHolderFreeText
{
    TextView hTextTitle;
    TextView hTextDetail;
    ImageView hIcon;
}

// View Holder for Checkbox Items
/**
 * Class for holding different view items
 * 
 */
static class ViewHolderCheckbox {
    TextView hTextTitle;
    TextView hTextDetail;
    CheckBox hCheckBox;
}
```

Trace

```
  09-23 15:36:29.105: D/AndroidRuntime(8908): Shutting down VM 09-23 15:36:29.105: W/dalvikvm(8908): threadid=1: thread exiting with
 uncaught exception (group=0x40014760) 09-23 15:36:29.326:
 E/AndroidRuntime(8908): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-23 15:36:29.326:
 E/AndroidRuntime(8908): java.lang.ClassCastException:
 com.techmelo.ws.CustomizeLViewAdapter$ViewHolderBranch cannot be cast
 to com.techmelo.ws.CustomizeLViewAdapter$ViewHolderFreeText 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 com.techmelo.ws.CustomizeLViewAdapter.getView(CustomizeLViewAdapter.java:157)
 09-23 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):    at
 android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1943) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1756) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:656) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:620) 09-23 15:36:29.326:
 E/AndroidRuntime(8908):    at
 android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4350)
 09-23 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):    at
 android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2892) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3566) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:4600) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1488)
 09-23 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):    at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1256) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
 09-23 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):    at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
 09-23 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):    at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
 09-23 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):    at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
 09-23 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):    at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
 09-23 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):    at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
 09-23 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):    at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
 09-23 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):    at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1700)
 09-23 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):    at
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1270)
 09-23 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):    at
 android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2277) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1680)
 09-23 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):    at
 android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2272) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1958) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126) 09-23 15:36:29.326:
 E/AndroidRuntime(8908):    at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491) 09-23 15:36:29.326:
 E/AndroidRuntime(8908):    at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
 09-23 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):    at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599) 09-23
 15:36:29.326: E/AndroidRuntime(8908):  at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-23 15:36:39.334:
 W/ActivityThread(9001): Application com.techmelo.ws is waiting for the
 debugger on port 8100... 09-23 15:36:39.345: I/System.out(9001):
 Sending WAIT chunk 09-23 15:36:39.364: I/dalvikvm(9001): Debugger is
 active 09-23 15:36:39.554: I/System.out(9001): Debugger has connected
 09-23 15:36:39.554: I/System.out(9001): waiting for debugger to
 settle... 09-23 15:36:39.808: I/System.out(9001): waiting for debugger
 to settle... 09-23 15:36:40.014: I/System.out(9001): waiting for
 debugger to settle... 09-23 15:36:40.216: I/System.out(9001): waiting
 for debugger to settle... 09-23 15:36:40.416: I/System.out(9001):
 waiting for debugger to settle... 09-23 15:36:40.647:
 I/System.out(9001): waiting for debugger to settle... 09-23
 15:36:40.884: I/System.out(9001): waiting for debugger to settle...
 09-23 15:36:41.085: I/System.out(9001): waiting for debugger to
 settle... 09-23 15:36:41.299: I/System.out(9001): waiting for debugger
 to settle... 09-23 15:36:41.524: I/System.out(9001): waiting for
 debugger to settle... 09-23 15:36:41.755: I/System.out(9001): debugger
 has settled (1390) 09-23 15:36:42.994: D/dalvikvm(9001): GC_FOR_ALLOC
 freed 63K, 4% free 6386K/6599K, paused 45ms 09-23 15:36:43.004:
 I/dalvikvm-heap(9001): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.820MB for
 513744-byte allocation 09-23 15:36:43.284: D/dalvikvm(9001):
 GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 6888K/7111K, paused 29ms+2ms 09-23
 15:36:46.084: V/TLINE(9001): new: android.text.TextLine@40719db0 09-23
 15:36:47.904: V/TLINE(9001): new: android.text.TextLine@4072b720 09-23
 15:37:11.404: D/dalvikvm(9001): threadid=1: still suspended after undo
 (sc=1 dc=1) 09-23 15:37:11.414: D/dalvikvm(9001): GC_CONCURRENT freed
 117K, 4% free 7263K/7495K, paused 13ms+8ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is happening because your different code branches (for the different types of rows) could each be dealing with a re-used row view that has any kind of tag object associated with it.

The best solution is to override `Adapter`'s `getItemViewType(int)` and `getViewTypeCount()` methods to specify how many different types of item views you have and map those to the list positions. This will simplify your logic in `getView(...)` and let `ListView` handle the row recycling pools differently for different view types.

You can change your tests in `getView(...)` to something like:

```
if (getItemViewType(_position) == TYPE_CATEGORY) {
   // code for categories
}
```

Where `TYPE_CATEGORY` is an `int` that your Adapter subclass knows about.

Comment: Thanks for your response i will try but you can see in my question statement that with this function call `itemList.get(_position).getType()` i am already getting the type and if position is ok then it should return the right value ... any feedback? yet m goin to try the method you suggested

Comment: The test you're doing is fine, for your purposes, but ListView knows nothing about the types of rows, so it's putting them all into one recycling queue and giving them back to you without regard to the type of "holder" you have attached to them.